# Glue crawl space rigid insulation

Tags: insulation, glue, cinderblock

I've dug a [trench](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4006/curtain-drain-in-the-crawl-space) around the perimeter of my crawl space.  Then I [planned](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4011/curtain-drain-in-the-crawl-space-part-2) the next steps.  I took a week off but I'd like to finish this project next weekend.  I am going to glue [2" R-10 FOAMULAR 250 Rigid Foam Insulation](http://insulation.owenscorning.com/homeowners/insulation-products/foamular-250.aspx) to the cinder block using [Liquid Nails FRP](http://www.liquidnails.com/products/product.jsp?productId=26).

Is this a good choice of materials?

The Liquid Nails instructions say that I should cover the whole area of the panels and 1 gallon is going to cover about 50 sq.ft.  How important is to really do that?  Do I really have to cover the panels or is it going to be OK to put less liquid nails material, perhaps just lines at the edges or even just a few spots at the corners?  I'm asking because the glue is not that cheap and I don't want to overdo this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to give the panels 100% coverage.  Just get some on the edges and a few good daps here and there. As long as it sticks to the wall, you should be OK.  Once you backfill the bottom, the panels shouldn't go anywhere.